# How to select element that contains only the class of "foobar", don't select if it contains any other classes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I only want to select the element if it has one class and that class is 'foobar'.

```
<style>
.foobar {
    /* only apply to an element if the element has a class and the only class is 'foobar'. */
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="foobar">i should be selected</div>

<div class="foobar ipsum">i should not be selected</div>
```

I know I could select it with adding a style for .foobar.ipsum { do one thing } and .foobar { something else } but I don't have control over the additional classes. Basically when the element has only the foobar class, I know it's my element and coming from somewhere else. This is what happens when CSS Library worlds collide. I know that there are deeper issues to resolve here but this is stumping me right now.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The simplest way with pure CSS is to use an attribute selector:

```
[class="foobar"] {
    /* only apply to an element if the element has a class and the only class is 'foobar'. */
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

You may not have control over the other elements, but if you have control over yours and you can modify its `class` attribute, [mayabelle makes a good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547088/with-css-selector-only-how-to-select-element-that-contains-only-the-class-of-f/19547156#19547156) about assigning your element its own special class and selecting by that class instead. That way you explicitly state which element is yours rather than going by the assumption that not having additional classes means it's yours.

Comment: This works. Thank you and thanks to others that offered solutions. I agree with @mayabelle 's solution but right now finding all of the current elements in the code base would be a nightmare (it's a mess *sigh*) so this solution will work best for now.

Comment: @teewuane: Yep, that's fine too.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
[class="foobar"] {
    background: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dA2dp/

Answer (score 4):

If it's "your element", can you apply an additional class to it? Then you can select using that:

```
<style>
.foobar.yourClass {
    /* your css */
}
</style>

<div class="foobar yourClass">i should be selected</div>
<div class="foobar ipsum">i should not be selected</div>
```

Comment: I agree with you. At this point the code base is a total mess and would be a nightmare to add this additional class to those elements. I'd explain but it'd take a while haha. So I'll use the attribute selector in the answers above to solve my problem at hand and not worry about old versions of IE. Thanks!