# PrimeNG Breadcrumb Component generates weird "/"

Tags: angular, primeng, breadcrumbs

[I tried to add a breadcrumb in my Angular-Project using primeng. I quickly encountered that weird "/" over my little arrows between each breadcrumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Ews.png)

-I added the BreadcrumbModule from Primeng in my app.module and the component im using it in(Also using Primeng Themes+Flex)
-I looked up different forum posts but couldnt find any solution
-Also tried to just hide it in my css but either my code is wrong or you arent realy able to hide it:
-Upon researching I could only find out that this part is generated by "li.p-breadcrumb-chevron.pi-circle-fill.ng-star-inserted::before"

html code:

```
<p-breadcrumb [model]="breadcrumbItems" [home]="home">
</p-breadcrumb>
```

.ts code:

```
    this.home = { icon: 'pi pi-home', routerLink: "/"};

    this.breadcrumbItems = [
      { label: "System", routerLink: "component1"},
      {label: "user", routerLink: "component2"}
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`BrowserAnimationModule`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792932/angular-5-adds-ng-star-inserted-in-some-classes-what-is-that) might be the culprit for this class getting added, anyway you can just get rid of this by using the below CSS

global styles.css (Fix in global styles)

```
li.p-breadcrumb-chevron .ng-star-inserted {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Fix on the component scss file using `::ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep li.p-breadcrumb-chevron .ng-star-inserted {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[Stackblitz - issue not reproducible](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much, i already added the BrowserAnimationsModule and it didnt work but the custom css fixed the problem :)